# Unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'android()'! after upgrading the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After upgrading Android Studio to version 0.8.0 I am getting this error:

> Unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'android()'!

here is the build.gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.incidentreport.app'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Why do you have three copies of the `appcompat-v7` dependency? Does your top-level `build.gradle` file apply the `android` plugin?

Comment: Thanks. I just added the following line to my build.gradle first line and it solved the issue.  apply plugin: 'android'